# How to use variables to configure Swiper's breakpoints in React?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

This code works:

```
<Swiper
breakpoings={{
    400: {
       // config
    }
}}
```

But this code does not work:

```
const sm = 400;
<Swiper
breakpoings={{
    sm: {
       // config
    }
}}
```

Why it's so? How can I use variables in Swiper's breakpoints in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to name object key by variable you need to wrap it in square brackets.

```js
const sm = 400;
<Swiper
  breakpoints={{
    [sm]: {
       // config
    }
  }}
```